# ColdFusion Builder and Eclipse Quick Diff

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, eclipse-plugin, coldfusionbuilder

I have installed ColdFusion builder (CFBuilder) (v3.2.1) as Eclipse (v4.17) plugin and I see that the Quick Diff functionality does not work with CFML Multi Page Editor.

I am using the Code Assist Dictionary Version as ColdFusion 2018.

I am not sure if this a bug in the CFBuilder or I am missing something here?

Comment: My opinion is that CF Builder and Eclipse are both antiquated ways to build CF apps. I’ve long since migrated over to VS Code with ColdFusion extensions installed. Sublime Text 3 is also a good alternative.

Comment: Ask in the official Adobe ColdFusion Builder support forum. You're more likely to get a response there. https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion/bd-p/coldfusion?page=1&sort=latest_replies&filter=all

Comment: I have already asked but no luck. https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion/coldfusion-builder-and-eclipse-quick-diff/m-p/11600507?page=1